# Nerd Dinner - labels for textfields are broken

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nerddinner

I am trying to learn ASP.NET (since I know C#) so I have decided to follow Nerd Dinner Tutorial. I am having trouble in [part 5 of tutorial](http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part5.htm). I exactly followed tutorial, even **pasted whole code** to my visual studio, but when I was supposed to create **EDIT VIEW**, my result was different than one in tutorial.

Please take a look at following pictures and think, where might problem be. I did not customise anything, everything is default. Please look at the images below.

http://i49.tinypic.com/wweooi.png

http://i46.tinypic.com/21oaufd.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you would not have added the CSS file. Add that and it should be fine.

HTH

Comment: Yes that was the issue. Thank you Raja. If someone ever will be going thru this tutorial, note that it had been done in VS 2008, I am using VS 2010.